# Choose the full namespace/class/function in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

-edit- nevermind i was lucky and didnt need to change much and have this test working.

I am doing a quick test and i need to choose the full path to a function.

in C# i can write

```
namespace ABC { class DEF { static string Test() { return "A test"; } } }
```

and can access it with `ABC.DEF.Test()` i tried

```
Namespace ABC 
    Partial Public Class DEF 
        Public Function Test(ByVal v As String) As String
            Return "A Test"
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

and i got `VBTest.ABC.DEF.Test()`. How do i get rid of VBTest which is the name of my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the project properties under the `Application` section - it will have a `Root Namespace` entry that you can change (remove VBTest from it).